# Enqueue script on every page except one

Tags: functions, pages, wp-enqueue-script

I want to load my javascript and exclude 1 page, so I tried the following without success:

```
function mypage_scripts()

{
if ( !is_admin() )
{ 
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js', true, '1.6.2', false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
/* My Script */ 
if ( !is_page('contact') )
        {       
            wp_enqueue_script('myscript', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/myscript.js', array('jquery'), '1.1', false);
        }
}

}

add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'mypage_scripts');
```

The result is that the script loads on every page except on Admin (as expected) but can't manage to not load on "Contact" page.

Any ideas?

Of course I can list all the pages I want to load it, but as the site is going to have more pages in the future I don't want to change the functions.php file everytime a new one is created.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't put it in `header.php`? Is it essential to have it in `functions.php`?

Comment: Not essential in this case in particular, but will be usefull if there's an option to do it in functions.php

Comment: You're correct in using the functions.php file. You shouldn't link to js in your header like suggested by Alexey.

Comment: There's no need for that `is_admin` check, not when using the `wp_print_scripts` action(that particular action, if i'm not mistaken, only runs on non-admin pages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving your function its own parameters and do a template_redirect, **something like this:**

```
<?php
  function mypage_scripts() {
    if ( !is_admin() ) {
      wp_deregister_script('jquery');
      wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js', true, '1.6.2', false);
      wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
      /* My Script */ 
  function contact_form_script() {
      if ( !is_page('contact') ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('myscript', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/myscript.js', array('jquery'), '1.1', false);
        }
      }
  add_action( 'template_redirect', 'contact_form_script' );
    }
  add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'mypage_scripts');
  }
  ?>
```

I've not checked this, but I believe it will work.

**I Checked this one on on one of my themes and it worked:.**

```
<?php
  function mypage_scripts() {
    if ( !is_admin() ){ 
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js', true, '1.6.2', false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
      }
    add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'mypage_scripts');
    }
  function contact_form_script() {
      if ( !is_page('contact') ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('myscript', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/myscript.js', array('jquery'), '1.1', false);
        }
      }
  add_action( 'template_redirect', 'contact_form_script' );
  ?>
```

**NOTE:**
The one thing I did diferent on my test is I wasn't using the Google scripts. Maybe that is giving you the issue?

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, tested but not worked.

Comment: I revised my answer after checking the first one and it didn't work for me. The second worked with the noted difference in our code.

Comment: @aurrutia Then mark it as _The Answer_ please.